# Vega-Lite / Kibana difference to manage URL object

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, vega-lite, vega

I found an interesting [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64375357/vega-lite-kibana-difference-to-manage-json-object) that used several data models on Vega-Lite. Tabular data were combined by key like in relational databases.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v2.json",
    "title": "Test",
    "datasets": {
        "stores": [
        {"cmdb_id1": 1, "group": "type1"},
        {"cmdb_id1": 2, "group": "type1"},
        {"cmdb_id1": 3, "group": "type2"}
        ],
        "labelsTimelines": [
        {"cmdb_id2": 1, "value": 83},
        {"cmdb_id2": 2, "value": 53},
        {"cmdb_id2": 3, "value": 23}
        ]
    },
    "data": {"name": "stores"},
    "transform": [
        {
        "lookup": "cmdb_id1",
        "from": {
            "data": {"name": "labelsTimelines"},
            "key": "cmdb_id2",
            "fields": ["value"]
        }
        }
    ],
    "mark": "bar",
    "encoding": {
        "y": {"aggregate": "sum", "field": "value", "type": "quantitative"},
        "x": {"field": "group", "type": "ordinal"}
    }
}
```

[Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAEyUAVhDYA7EABoQmOoLhoQAFTgRMikABMkmJBDiYIaULrYAnHWgDaoKAgNMA+jQMBGND6UyWzYGHA1MAE8cOD8AXwUXN09vP1QxQODQ8KiYkHjE9y9fNABmDJCw9EjosTyAXSVBJCY4QQhNGgRWmlkHVGcQV0LvWtQAkGIkQQZ1VAAOEvzBpKLR9ImpmbQAVkWE5eGDUbKN6dmxRbr4w2MUVFBZJC6NG3tLa8xbJFkIADM7BBOUCCNhsADWWXQQ2SxSUv2CgPuNxMVhAj2e6CaLTaHS6wl67yUYLgEQ00NW+l+NFaBks-VOWyusQaIGQtjBGiYSFs+jgsigbAMPTIqNJSKQZCCfEwsxAEAYgLh1MEBg0kzO+mqsoAjgxvioTCpSHklAAPVFUmkaIIVTU5DR2IWPQR5WKxIA)

The question arose as to whether it was possible to obtain the same result using the construction:

"data": {"url": "...."}

Changed the source for Elasticsearch query:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v3.json",
    
    "datasets": {
        "stores": [{
        "url": {
        "%context%": "true"
        "index": "test_cmdb"
        "body": {
            "size": 1000,
            "_source": ["cmdb_id", "street","group"]
        }
        }
        format: {property: "hits.hits"}
    }]}
    
    "data": {
        "name": "stores"
    },
    
    "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "url.body.size", "type": "ordinal", "title": "X"},
        "y": {"field": "url.body.size", "type": "ordinal", "title": "Y"}
    },
    "layer": [
        {
        "mark": "rect",
        
        "encoding": {
            "tooltip": [
            {"field": "url"}]
        }
        }
        
    ]
}
```

I understand that there is a syntactical error, the data did not come from Elasticsearch.

Thanks in advance!

[example.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXVNJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not currently possible to specify URL data within top-level `"datasets"`. The relevant open feature request in Vega-Lite is here: https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/4004.

Answer (score 0):

Your much better off using Vega rather than Vega-lite for this. In Vega you can specify as many datasets as you like with a URL. For example...

```
...
data: [
  {
    name: dataset_1
    url: {
      ...
    }
  }
  {
    name: dataset_2
    url: {
      ...
    }
  }
]
...
```

This can actually get very interesting since it means you can combine data from multiple indices into one visualisation.

I know this is late, but figured this might help people who are looking around.